# ASP.NET MVC w/ Entity Framework - UpdateException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am encountering a problem when I go to update an object in my database using Entity Framework.

Firstly, the concept is:

A user can be a member of a group, hence a Group contains Users.

To model this in the database, I have the following structure:

Users: 
    ID
    Name
    etc.

Groups: 
    ID
    Name

GroupMembers: 
    GroupID
    UserID

Both fields in GroupMembers are foreign keys relating back to the User ID and Group ID. When I load this into Entity Framework, it is modelled correctly in that a Group object has a list of User objects, and each User object has a list of Group objects.

However, when I go to add a User to a Group, I get the following problem:

```
var group = DAO.GetGroup(GroupID);
var user = DAO.GetUser(UserID);
group.Users.Add(user);
conn.SaveChanges();
```

> Unable to update the EntitySet
>   'GroupMembers' because it has a
>   DefiningQuery and no 
>   element exists in the
>    element
>   to support the current operation.

I have seen various pieces online advising to add an ID field to the GroupMembers table - however if I do that, I get a mapping error in EF that complains about the ID not being mapped to anything.

Would anybody be able to lend some other advice, or a workaround?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What is the PK of `GroupMembers` ? It *should be* both columns. Did you customize the `DefiningQuery` ?

Comment: No I haven't customized the DefiningQuery, mainly because I didn't know what to change it to and didn't want to adversely affect things more than I already have! GroupMembers doesn't have a primary key at all, I did add a single "ID" column, but the mapping threw an error as it wasn't mapped properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ID` column from `GroupMembers`. Create a PK for `GroupMembers` consisting of *both* `GroupID` and `UserID`. Now right-click your model and update it from the DB.

The EF designer needs to know that the pair of `GroupID` and `UserID` is unique in order to get the cardinality right.

Answer (score 0):

By making both fields in GroupMembers the primary key, I can now add to the table.

Thanks for your help :-)

Chris